# bcrypt.compare gives a TypeError

Tags: authentication, typeerror, undefined, next.js13, bcryptjs

I'm working on a project using `Next.js v14.0.0`.
I'm using `MongoDB Atlas`. I'm working on a login form. I'm trying to perform a login operation.

I've been experiencing a problem, when using bcryptjs (`"bcryptjs": "^2.4.3"`).

Whenever I use this command:

```
const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
```

It gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'compare').
```

I've checked the arguments `password` (the value from the input element of the login form) and `user.password` (the hashed password, from the database).
They both have the right expected values.
They are both of type `string`.

I've tried to use callback function, with no sucess.
I've tried to use `bcrypt.compareSync`, with no sucess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
import { compare } from 'bcrypt';
const passwordsMatch = await compare(password, user.password);
```